# Make friends based on BOOL status, finding difficult comparing the array value , Firebase, Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, swift3

I am making a chat app,I want to make friends only under the condition that, if a **userA** has friends **userB** == **ture** and the same **userB** has **userA** == **true** , I want them to make friend. To make you more clear here is the **json** format:

```
user_friends: {
$userA: {
  friends: {
    $userB: true
  }
},
$userB: {
  friends: {
    $userA: true,
    $userC: true
  }
},
$userC: : {
  friends: {
    $userA: true,
    $userB: true
  }
 }
}
```

As the **json** above , **userA** will have **userB** as friend, **userB** will have **userA** & **userC** as friend and **userC** will have only **userB** as friend because **userA** do not have **userC** as his friend. Here is my data model, not sure if it is perfect

```
import Foundation
import SwiftyJSON

struct Friends {
var myFriends:[Bool]!

struct Friend {
let key: String
let is_friend: Bool
init(snap: FIRDataSnapshot) {
    self.key = snap.key
    self.is_friend = (snap.value != nil)
   }
}
```

And here is the function by which I am trying to fetch the data and compare them, but its not working as I want

```
    func getFriendList() {

    if self.user != nil {
            _ = self.ref.child("user_friends").child((user?.uid)!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                for snap in snapshot.children {
                  for friends in (snap as AnyObject).children {
                    // cast friend and append to myFriends
                    print(friends)
                    let friend = Friend(snap: friends as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                    self.myFriends.append(friend)
                    print("my friends are\(self.myFriends.description)")
                    print("friends count\(self.myFriends.count)")

                    if (self.myFriends.count > 0) {
                        for friend in self.myFriends {
                            _ = self.ref
                                .child("user_friends")
                                .child(friend.key)
                                .child("friends")
                                //.child((self.user?.uid)!)
                                .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                                print("Desired Snapshot\(snapshot)")
                                //Now I need to check the condition here

                          })
                        }
                      }
                    }
                }
            })


    }//FIRAuth ends here

}//getFriendList ends here
```

And here is my actual database design:[image: friends] and the debug result [image] I guess I need to take two dictionary and compare their values. Its almost like **instagram** feature that if someone follows a user and the user follow him back they got message option enabled , message option does not open until they follow each other. Please any kind person come forward and help me. I am in real trouble. Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused. Wouldn't it be more logical that you assumed that one person cannot be befriended to someone if the other guy isn't befriended to him?

Comment: Yes your answer is correct , I am finding trouble to fix it. The catch is, I need to find the **userID** of the users who are friend to current firebase user. Then using those **userID** I need to see if the current firebase user exist in their friend list . If its true then they are friends. Just finding it difficult, couldn't solve it until now :(

Comment: Yeah but I mean, wouldn't it make more sense that if a user is in the currentUser's friends list then they're friends, without checking if the currentUser is also in the other user's friends list. That's sort of the whole point of the data fan-out method.

Comment: my client requirement is , when a userA like a post of UserB and UserB also like a post of UserA, then they are friends. Thats why I have to go through this.

Comment: Yes I know, I solved your last question. But with my code it would never happen that a currentUser has a friend that doesn't have the currentUser as a friend.

Comment: @Pieter , I have updated the question according to your answer , would you please have a look ? Please kind man ...

Comment: No I meant I solved this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42718141/how-to-make-friends-based-on-follow-follower-swift-firebase/42720440#42720440 I just meant that all of this is obsolete. Just get the currentUsers friends list, it will always be synced with the other user's friends list. There is no need to check whether they're in eachother's friends list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing alot of looping and parsing that you dont need to. This is how I would do what you are trying to do:

```
// A struct for friend nodes on a user account
struct Friend {
    let key: String
    let is_friend: Bool
    init(snap: FIRDataSnapshot) {
        self.key = snap.key
        self.is_friend = snap.value as! Bool
    }
}
// A struct for user account nodes
struct ChatUser {
    var friends = [Friend]()
    let user_ref: FIRDatabaseReference
    let key: String
    init(user_ref: FIRDatabaseReference) {
        self.user_ref = user_ref
        self.key = user_ref.key
    }
}

let currentUser = ChatUser(user_ref: self.user.ref)

func getFriendListForUser(user: ChatUser) {
    _ = user.ref.child("user_friends").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        for friend in snapshot.children {
            // cast friend and append to myFriends
            let friend = Friend(snap: friend)
            user.friends.append(friend)
        }
    })
}

// validate friend list in firebase for a given chat user
func validatedFriendsForUser(user: ChatUser) {
    for friend in user.friends {
        _ = FIRDatabase.database()
            .reference(withPath: friend.key)
            .child("friends")
            .child(self.currentUser.key)
            .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
                if let status = snapshot as? Bool {
                    friend.is_friend = status
                }
            })
    }

    // Remove friends which are not confirmed in firebase
    self.currentUser.friends = user.friends.filter{ $0 }
}
// call our methods to fetch and filter user friends for current user
self.getFriendListForUser(user: self.currentUser)
self.validatedFriendsForUser(user: self.currentUser)
```

The validatedFriendsForUser() is not required, but if you want to check to see if user A has user B's key set to `true` in the database.

Comment: in your **getFriendList** function if you do **myFriends.append(friend)** , it will simply append all the friend data in the array, which is not my purpose. I want the filtered list as I mentioned in the question. Please help .

Comment: That is what the `validatedFriendsForUser()` method is for. We need to gather all friends for the current user under the `friends` key in the database. We then loop through all the friend keys to verify the current user's id is set to true in their respective `user` nodes. The result is a `ChatUser` object with an array of `Friend` objects representing all the user's verified friends in the database. Does this help?

Comment: your answer was perfect , it took me a while to grab it but thanks for your great answer.